# Two windows appear instead of one using Rust

Tags: rust

I tried loading the `minimal.html`, it is loading fine at cargo run, but once I runn the .exe alone, 2 windows appear, one empty console windows and one shows the real output as shown in this pic.

I'm using `Windows 10 x64`

My `main.rs` is:

```
extern crate sciter;

fn main() {
    let html = include_bytes!("minimal.htm");
    let mut frame = sciter::Window::new();
    frame.load_html(html, None);
    frame.run_app();
}
```

The `Cargo.toml` is:

```
[package]
name = "rust_sciter"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Home"]

[dependencies]
sciter-rs = "0.4.24"
```

The `minimal.html` is:

```
<html window-icon="https://sciter.com/wp-content/themes/sciter/!images/favicon.ico">
<head>
  <title>Minimalistic Sciter demo</title>
  <style>
    html {
      background: radial-gradient(75% 75%, circle farthest-side, white, orange, rgb(0,0,204));
      color:#fff;
    }
    html:rtl {
      mapping: left-to-right(background);
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/tiscript">
    view.caption = $(head > title).value;
    $(#machine).text = Sciter.machineName();
    var counter = 0;
    $(button#append).on("click", function(){
      $(body).$append(<h1#test>{++counter }</h1>);
    });
    $(button#open).on("click", function(){
      var fn = view.selectFile(#open,
        "HTML Files (*.htm,*.html)|*.HTM;*.HTML|All Files (*.*)|*.*" , "html" );
      stdout.println("selected file: " + fn);
      $(body).$append(<h1#test>{fn}</h1>);
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Minimal Sciter Application</h1>
<p>Running on <em #machine /> machine</p>

<button #append>Append</button>
<button #open>Open</button>
<select>
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option>Third</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

The app structure, code and output are below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/sciter-sdk/rust-sciter/blob/master/examples/minimal.rs#L3..L6), `#![windows_subsystem="windows"]` is required to be used in the top of the code, so my code became:

```
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
extern crate sciter;

fn main() {
    let html = include_bytes!("minimal.htm");
    let mut frame = sciter::Window::new();
    frame.load_html(html, None);
    frame.run_app();
}
```